# Parsing a boolean json value in jQuery

Tags: jquery

In this fiddle I'm just trying to return true : http://jsfiddle.net/WCFtp/ for jQuery key 'saved'

Why do I receive the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s"

Code below :

```
        var test = "{saved: true}";
        var jsonSaveResponse = jQuery.parseJSON(test);
        alert(jsonSaveResponse.saved);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be `var test = '{"saved": true}';`.

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON isn't valid.  Object attribute names must be quoted:

```
var test = '{"saved": true}';
```

Keep in mind, JSON is a subset of valid Javascript syntax.  Lots of valid Javascript is invalid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

See the [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) docs.

> Passing in a malformed JSON string may result in an exception being
> thrown. For example, the following are all malformed JSON strings:
>
> {test: 1} (test does not have double quotes around it).
>
> {'test': 1} ('test' is using single quotes instead of double quotes).

You'll want to use this instead:

```
var test = "{\"saved\": true}";
```